# How to disable dial sounds on an iPhone XR running iOS 13.2.3?

Tags: iphone

On an iPhone XR running iOS 13.2.3, how do I disable dial sounds? By that I mean how do I turn off the beep I get when I tap each digit of a phone number that I am calling. There does not seem to be a way to do this from Settings | Sounds & Haptics, which gives an option to disable "Keyboard Clicks" (which I have disabled) but not these dial sounds.

Comment: Have you set the ring/silent switch to silent?

Comment: No - I want the phone to continue to ring when someone calls it.